# 2-WAY TLS/SSL Authentiction

Tags: web-services, ssl, https

We have a WS client as a cloud service that needs to communicate with a web service hosted in our corporate network. We have setup an Apache reverse proxy (RP) in the DMZ zone, which accepts incoming requests from the WS client. The RP is exposing an HTTPS interface to the client. Right now at the RP, the SSL configuration is 1way, but we want to convert it to 2way SSL. The main reason is that we want the client to authenticate itself by presenting a client certificate to the RP server.

So I want to understand if we need changes in the following:

- RP configuration change from 1way to 2way SSL? Any pointers how?
- Securing a client certificate for the WS client (cloud service)? What details are required for this client certificate to be requested with CA?
- Does RP need a client certificate to perform 2way SSL configuration?
- Any other important point to take into consideration for enabling 2way SSL?
  Many thanks.